# Eloquent: Constraining an eager load relation where relation property is 0 or relation doesn't exist

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I would like to get all the `Report` models where the relation `ReportUpload`'s property of `status` equals 0 *or* where the `ReportUpload` relation doesn't exist. The `Report` and `ReportUpload` models have a one to one relationship, `ReportUpload` belongs to a `Report`.

Somewhat unsure how to go about this using eloquent's relationship constraints or any other method. Any help would be appreciated.

Here's my current code:

```
// initial query

$reports = Report::whereHas('link', function($query) {
        $query->where('status', 'complete');
    })->with('student', 'course', 'institution', 'reportUpload');


// apply constraint

if ($request->has('uploadStatus')) {
    $uploadStatus = $request->has('uploadStatus'); // 0 or 1

    if ($uploadStatus === 0) {
        $reports = $reports
            ->whereDoesntHave('reportUpload')
            ->orWhereHas('reportUpload', function($query) use ($uploadStatus) {
                $query->where('status', $uploadStatus);
            });
    } else {
        $reports = $reports->whereHas('reportUpload', function($query) use ($uploadStatus) {
            $query->where('status', $uploadStatus);
        });
    }
}
```

The code does not produce the desired results.

**Edit**

Trying this approach but not sure if it's correct:

```
$reports = $reports
    ->where(function ($query) use ($uploadStatus) {
        $query
            ->whereDoesntHave('reportUpload')
            ->orWhereHas('reportUpload', function($query) use ($uploadStatus) {
                $query->where('status', $uploadStatus);
            });
    });
```

Comment: Perhaps [whereDoesnHave](https://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_whereDoesntHave) might help?

Comment: Are you suggesting I use it? Because it's already in my code in the question. If you meant something else please clarify, thank you.

Comment: Excuse me, @haakym, I've misunderstood the question, I don't think my previous comment is relevant. Sorry!

Comment: No worries at all! Thanks for stopping by.

Comment: @haakym wrap your `or` parts in another `where` (thus in `(... OR ...)`) otherwise the query does completely different thing to what you'd expect.

Comment: @JarekTkaczyk thanks for your reply. I understand what you mean, but don't understand how I can wrap two eloquent `where` constraints in a `where`? I get how to do that with the query builder but not with eloquent. Any advice?

Comment: Eloquent is no other than query builder - eloquent uses the Query Builder under the hood. Just `where(function ($q) { $q->where()->orWhere();})` - there's an answer below that shows it already

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out in the end

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, there are some mistakes in your initial code.

1 - You're checking if the request `has` an uploadStatus. Then, `$uploadStatus == $request->has` which will always be `true`.

```
if ($request->has('uploadStatus')) {
    $uploadStatus = $request->has('uploadStatus');
```

So I guess you might want:

```
if ($request->has('uploadStatus')) {
    $uploadStatus = $request->input('uploadStatus');
```

2 - You're comparing strictly `$uploadStatus === 0` which might not work because the request might return a string `'0'` and not an integer, so you should either compare with `==` or cast `$uploadStatus` to `(int)`.

After this, I think the code you added in your question works as expected:

```
$reports = $reports
->where(function ($query) use ($uploadStatus) {
    $query
        ->whereDoesntHave('reportUpload')
        ->orWhereHas('reportUpload', function($query) use ($uploadStatus) {
            $query->where('status', $uploadStatus);
        });
});
```

Because the `where` encapsulating the query will put it between parentheses.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I can't believe I missed all those mistakes will give the corrections a shot and get back to you.

Comment: Works just as I wanted! Many thanks for your help and credit to @jarek-tkaczyk for the tip on the query.

Answer (score 1):

Try to separate the queries. `whereDoesntHave` might be counting negatively with the `orWhereHas` even if it is an `or` statement:

```
$reportsNoUpload = $reports
            ->whereDoesntHave('reportUpload')->get();

$reportsIncomplete = $reports
            ->orWhereHas('reportUpload', function($query) use ($uploadStatus) {
                $query->where('status', $uploadStatus);
            })->get();

$reports = $reportsNoUpload->merge($reportsIncomplete);
```

Comment: The issue with this approach is that I don't want to perform `get()` because I have a huge data set which is being paginated using the laravel datatables package.